# How to apply unit testing on react project?

Tags: reactjs

Basically, I do not know how to implement unit test on react projects. Please, anyone, provide me resources for implementing unit test on react project.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

React uses `jest` as its default testing library, but you can swap out and put in any other testing library you want.
The docs are [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html)